# Is it possible to fetch only a single document based on a field in Cloud-Firestore?

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, nosql

is there a possibility to fetch a document based on a field? For example, if I have a collection called *users* that contains documents such as *"usrID1", "usrID2", ...*  and each has a field inside called "city", now, can I search the entire collection and fetch ONLY the ones that has the field "city" equal to "New York"?

I know if I do it this way `firebase.firestore().collection('users').get()` and then extract only the needed data like ....`doc.data().city` but this would cost me a lot as each user is fetching the entire collection whenever they query that, moreover, its risky as each user will have the data of all other users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use firebase.firestore().collection('users').where( "city", isEqualTo: "New York").get()

Comment: But, will this cost the same as fetching the entire collection?